# Magento form post action to custom controller not working - wrong routing, but why?

Tags: magento, routes, controller, magento-1.4

I have a form in my Magento store, the contact form. When I navigate to the form, it has this URL: *http://www.domain123.com/contact/*. There is a form and it looks like this:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="contactform/index/sendcontactmail">
    ...
</form>
```

Now, when I click the send button, it gives me a 404 not found and I know why. The URL it posts to is *http://www.domain123.com/contact/contactform/index/sendcontactmail*, which is not right of course, it has to be *http://www.domain123.com/contactform/index/sendcontactmail* (without contact). The question is, how do I solve this issue? The contact form as the frontname *contact* and my modules name is *contactform*. How would I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a leading slash to your form:

```php
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="/contactform/index/sendcontactmail">
```

Or if working from a .phtml template the safer way is to use a bit of PHP. This will insert the correct domain:

```php
<form id="contactForm" method="post"
    action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contactform/index/sendcontactmail') ?>">
```